# PushNotificationReceived event doesn't fire

Tags: c#, events, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I am developing Windows Phone 8.1 app and I have this issue.
I don't want my push notifications to pop when the app is in foreground - so when the notification received from `PushNotificationChannel` I am checking if the app is in the foreground on `PushNotificationReceived` event, if so, I am canceling the notification by:
args.

```
void channel_PushNotificationReceived(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    if(appInForeground)
    {
        args.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

My `PushNotification` background task (`IBackgroundTask`)  trigger is `PushNotificationTrigger`.

**The issue**:
Sometimes when the app is in foreground - I am receiving push notifications. When I look into logs I can see that `PushNotificationReceived` event didn't fire.
I am not unsubscribing form the event in my whole app life...

Can it be possible that the event didn't fire but my backgroundTask trigger did?

Something is fishy here...

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the push notificaton system of windows to suppress popup when the app is in foreground. So basically the xml for the push notification should have this property defined when sending a push to device.

> As of Windows Phone 8.1, the phone can also keep a toast notification from being displayed through use of the ToastNotification.suppressPopup or ScheduledToastNotification.suppressPopup property in the notification's XML content.

More details present in this link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/jj709908.aspx) . Hope this helps!

Comment: You are talking about toast notifications, my question is about PushNotifications which is received by PushNotificationChannel. Correct my if I'm wrong :)